# How to create a demo like Convertbot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

[Convertbot](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/convertbot/id308928075?mt=8) has an embedded demo that is accessed through their info button in the app.  However, it doesn't seem to use the Mediaplayer framework.  They've also managed to get the demo very small, since the total app size is only 1.8MB.  Any ideas how a demo like that can be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They created their own script using timers and callbacks to run through the app and show how to use it.  If you do this, just emulate a tap and disable user taps.

Comment: Wow!  That must be a huge amount of work right?  Far more than doing a screen recording I'd think.

Comment: I don't believe it is as hard as you think… but the result is something much better than a movie

Comment: What do yo mean by script?  And how can all user taps be disabled without disabling for each component?

Comment: YOu might want to try asking them but if I was going to do it, I would just setup timers that would call the functions directly, then place an invisible view on top of everything to disable the taps.  For example, if their ui elements are buttons, just call -[myView button1Pressed] directly and so on

Answer (score 2):

This was too long to leave as a comment on coneybeare's answer, but it builds off the idea.

Haven't had a chance to try it yet, but it sound theoretically similar to similar to Application Testing, as described in the [unit testing section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) of the iPhone Development Guide. The idea is that you programmatically interact with your apps UI.

The [iPhoneUnitTests](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/index.html) sample code has an example of doing this - you could possibly adapt it to move of a live app demo. Check CalcTests.m and look at methods like `testAddition` and `testSubtraction`.